# Javascript to fetch an Image Insted of displaying the Link

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

I need to display the image but I can only provide the link of the image which is generated.
and I need JavaScript to fetch that link and display that image instead of displaying the image link.

Comment: You can use `img.src = 'http://www.domain.com/img.png';` to set a a url to the image file.

Comment: And why <img src=""> isnt good for you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the image url in a variable, you can use the following code:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = your_url;
element.appendChild(img); // where element is a DOM element - as returned by document.getElementById()
```